# Why does clearing a canvas element and putting it back in make it glitch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

This is a problem with my last question that I posted, but when I clear the canvas, the objects just glitch out. It disappears and then appears. But why does it glitch? I set the interval to 0 MS, but it's just pop and then appear.

The little glitch is going on here: https://cmt-1.hoogidyboogidy.repl.co/

Probably it's just this device. I use laptop and computer. A windows 7 computer is pretty old and a chromebook, eh just bad.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = c.getContext('2d')

c.height = window.innerHeight
c.width = window.innerWidth

let blockInfo = {
    h: 15, // Defining height and width so they can be changed. (NOTE: The height and width doesn't have to be the same value)
    w: 15
}

let renderedObjects = false // Keep in case you're gonna make colission

let player = {
    speed: 0.125,
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    height: 1,
    width: 1
}

function clearObjects() {
    // Clear all
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
}

function renderObjects() {
    // Render block
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00b02f'
    ctx.fillRect(5 * blockInfo.w, 5 * blockInfo.h, blockInfo.w, blockInfo.h)

    // Render player
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
    ctx.fillRect(player.x * blockInfo.w, player.y * blockInfo.h, player.width * blockInfo.w, player.height * blockInfo.h)
}

function press(e) {
    let w = e.which
    
    if (renderedObjects == true) {
        clearObjects()
        
        if (w == 39) {
            player.x += player.speed
        } else if (w == 37) {
            player.x -= player.speed
        } else if (w == 38) {
            player.y -= player.speed
        } else if (w == 40) {
            player.y += player.speed
        }
    }
}

setInterval(function() {
    renderedObjects = false
    renderObjects()
    renderedObjects = true
}, 0)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body onkeydown="press(event)">
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setInterval`, use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Even though you specified 0 for `setInterval`, it will actually still wait some minimum delay before calling the callback again. This is unrelated to your device. `requestAnimationFrame` is specifically useful for... animations.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

let blockInfo = {
    h: 15, // Defining height and width so they can be changed. (NOTE: The height and width doesn't have to be the same value)
    w: 15
};

let renderedObjects = false; // Keep in case you're gonna make colission

let player = {
    speed: 0.125,
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    height: 1,
    width: 1
};

function clearObjects() {
    // Clear all
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}

function renderObjects() {
    // Render block
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00b02f';
    ctx.fillRect(5 * blockInfo.w, 5 * blockInfo.h, blockInfo.w, blockInfo.h);

    // Render player
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(player.x * blockInfo.w, player.y * blockInfo.h, player.width * blockInfo.w, player.height * blockInfo.h);
}

function press(e) {
    let w = e.which;
    
    if (renderedObjects == true) {
        clearObjects(); 
       
        if (w == 39) {
            player.x += player.speed;
        } else if (w == 37) {
            player.x -= player.speed;
        } else if (w == 38) {
            player.y -= player.speed;
        } else if (w == 40) {
            player.y += player.speed;
        }
    }
}

(function loop() {
    renderedObjects = false;
    renderObjects();
    renderedObjects = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body onkeydown="press(event)">
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unrelated: please terminate your statements with an explicit semi-colon. To rely on the [automatic semi colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) is just taking an extra risk of unintended errors.

Comment: Thanks! I never heard of requestAnimationFrame though.

Answer (score 2):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399637/6243352) solves the problem and offers great advice to use `requestAnimationFrame` which automatically batches all re-renders as part of its optimized animation support, there are more fundamental design issues at hand. The glitchy animation is more of a symptom of this than anything else.

Although `requestAnimationFrame` is smart enough to (inadvertently) bail the design out, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to use `setInterval` just fine (but don't use `setInterval` for other reasons than this).

The typical flow for animating is:

```
 ______________________
|| :synchronous code: ||  :asynchronous code:
||                    ||
||   [update state]<---------+
||          |         ||     |
||          v         ||     | (keypresses are collected, etc)
||   [clear screen]   ||     |
||          |         ||     |
||          v         ||     |
||   [redraw screen]---------+
`|____________________|`
```

However, your approach pulls screen clears out of the synchronous update block to fire at random points. There can be a delay before another run of the atomic update/render code has a chance to redraw the screen. If animation is like a flip book, this is like opening up the possibility of blank pages being shown.

A better way to approach this, regardless of how naive the rendering loop is (including `setInterval`), is to record keypresses and user input as it occurs but do nothing else (including screen clearing, position updates, etc). Then, once your update/render function gets another chance to run, you can update entity positions as a batch and perform all re-renders as a batch.

It may seem inefficient to clear and redraw the screen on every frame, but that's just how animation works. If you only want to clear and redraw when a key is pressed, that's fine, but then leave out the animation loop entirely and re-render the screen only in the key handler. This is fine for many applications, but if you're making a game, it's likely that you'll want enemies to move and things to happen in real-time, even if the player isn't pushing a button, so it probably won't help much in this case. The key is not to mix the two approaches.

All of this leads to decoupling the keyboard/UI from the game logic (player movement, etc). You can use a specific UI-to-game logic coupling module to handle translation of user input into player position changes and other state updates. This is the same idea as decoupling rendering logic from game/state update logic.

Entities are anything that's renderable (responds to a `render(ctx)` function). Thinking in terms of OOP, the `box` and `player` share the same base class--they're renderable rectangles, so we can build them with a constructor function of sorts and toss on the `speed` property for `player`.

Now, of course, some of this can be premature optimization for a small app like this, but you'll see it's more or less the same amount of code.

Putting together all of the points above, we get something like:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(canvas);
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const makeRectangleEntity = props => ({
  ...props,
  render: function (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
});

const block = makeRectangleEntity({
  x: 75, y: 75, w: 15, h: 15, color: "#00b02f"
});
const player = makeRectangleEntity({
  x: 20, y: 20, w: 15, h: 15, 
  color: "#000", speed: 0.125
});
const entities = [block, player];

const keyCodeActions = {
  37: () => (player.x -= player.speed),
  38: () => (player.y -= player.speed),
  39: () => (player.x += player.speed),
  40: () => (player.y += player.speed),
};

const keysPressed = new Set();
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  keysPressed.add(e.keyCode);
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  keysPressed.delete(e.keyCode);
});

// Show that setInterval wasn't the problem, but do
// replace this with requestAnimationFrame anyway.
setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // update entity state
  for (const keyCode of keysPressed) {
    if (keyCode in keyCodeActions) {
      keyCodeActions[keyCode]();
    }
  }
  
  // redraw screen
  entities.forEach(e => e.render(ctx));
}, 0);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me the details. It is very packed with details. Mine as well let your details go hiking since it's packed.

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind Stack Overflow is a community Q&A website so answers are here to help future readers in addition to you. If you need a TL;DR here, the answer is that you should synchronously run all of your update and rendering code at the same time in the update loop--don't clear the screen outside of the rendering loop in a keypress handler like this.